# Django attribute error due to login code and I can't get to run migrate

Tags: python, django

when I run python manage.py migrate

it show error urls.py", line 30, in 
url(r'^users/login/$', auth.login, {'template_name': 'login.html'}, name='login'),
AttributeError: module 'django.contrib.auth.views' has no attribute 'login'

I have shown code urls.py and views.py

urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from django.contrib import admin
from orders import views as my_order
from django.contrib.auth import views as auth
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^admin/', admin.site.urls),
    url(r'^$', my_order.index, name='home'),
    url(r'^orders$', my_order.index, name='home'),
    url(r'^order/(?P<order_id>\d+)/$', my_order.show, name='show'),
    url(r'^order/new/$', my_order.new, name='new'),
    url(r'^order/edit/(?P<order_id>\d+)/$', my_order.edit, name='edit'),
    url(r'^order/delete/(?P<order_id>\d+)/$', my_order.destroy, name='delete'),
    url(r'^users/login/$', auth.login, {'template_name': 'login.html'}, name='login'),
    url(r'^users/logout/$', auth.logout, {'next_page': '/'}, name='logout'),
    url(r'^users/change_password/$', login_required(auth.password_change), {'post_change_redirect' : '/','template_name': 'change_password.html'}, name='change_password'),
]
```

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .models import Order
from .forms import OrderForm
from django.contrib import messages
from django.contrib.auth.decorators import login_required

@login_required
def index(request):
    orders = Order.objects.all()
    return render(request, 'index.html', {'orders': orders})

@login_required
def show(request, order_id):
    order = Order.objects.filter(id=order_id)
    return render(request, 'show.html', {'order': order})

@login_required
def new(request):
    if request.POST:
        form = OrderForm(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            if form.save():
                return redirect('/', messages.success(request, 'Order was successfully created.', 'alert-success'))
            else:
                return redirect('/', messages.error(request, 'Data is not saved', 'alert-danger'))
        else:
            return redirect('/', messages.error(request, 'Form is not valid', 'alert-danger'))
    else:
        form = OrderForm()
        return render(request, 'new.html', {'form':form})

@login_required
def edit(request, order_id):
    order = Order.objects.get(id=order_id)
    if request.POST:
        form = OrderForm(request.POST, instance=order)
        if form.is_valid():
            if form.save():
                return redirect('/', messages.success(request, 'Order was successfully updated.', 'alert-success'))
            else:
                return redirect('/', messages.error(request, 'Data is not saved', 'alert-danger'))
        else:
            return redirect('/', messages.error(request, 'Form is not valid', 'alert-danger'))
    else:
        form = OrderForm(instance=order)
        return render(request, 'edit.html', {'form':form})

@login_required
def destroy(request, order_id):
    order = Order.objects.get(id=order_id)
    order.delete()
    return redirect('/', messages.success(request, 'Order was successfully deleted.', 'alert-success'))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`django.contrib.auth.views` does not have an attribute `login`.

Assuming you're attempting to load the `django` login page, you should be using `LoginView.as_view()` as per the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.views.LoginView).

Here is an example:

```
path('login/', views.LoginView.as_view(template_name='login/login.html', redirect_authenticated_user=True), name='login'),
path('logout/', views.LogoutView.as_view(template_name='login/logout.html'), name='logout'),
```